# Kendo ASP.NET MVC : Assigning differing functionality to buttons on a grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Java back-end guy thrown into .net fullstack(MVC, EF, Kendo, etc...) seeks help with assigning differing functionality to buttons on a grid(Kendo).

**What I am trying to accomplish:** Create custom/differing behaviors for 3 buttons.

- On my Index page/view, I have 3 buttons: Create, Edit, Delete.
- Create should direct the user to a new page/view: /Dies/Create
- Edit should direct the user to a new page/view: /Dies/Edit
- Delete should produce a popup window prompting the user with the standard

**Question:** Could you provide me with an elegant solution to my goals(proposed above)?

**Note:** As you'll see in my Index page/view, I've started attempting to implement a solution via the use of command.Custom & some js functions(located at the bottom of the file). But I don't have enough understand to feel confident about what I'm doing.

**Note:** I've included views below. Like wise, I have included my controller, logic, profile(mapping), & model for additional context.

**My pages/views:**

- Index.cshtml

```html
@model IEnumerable<LabelArchive.Models.Die.DieModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Die";
}

<h2>Die Management</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<LabelArchive.Models.Die.DieModel>()
    .Name("diesgrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(i => i.Name);
        columns.Bound(i => i.Width);
        columns.Bound(i => i.Height);
        columns.Bound(i => i.DieShapeName);
        columns.Bound(i => i.DieTypeName);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Custom("Edit").Click("editDie");
            command.Custom("Delete").Click("deleteDie");
        }).Width(250);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Text("Create").Action("Create", "Dies"))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(i => i.DieId))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Die_Read", "Dies"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Die_Delete", "Dies"))
    )
)

@*<script src="~/ViewScripts/kendo_generic.js"></script>*@

<script type="text/javascript">

    // error_handler
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function() {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    // createDie
    function createDie(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest('tr'));
        document.location.href = '@(Url.Action("Create", "Dies"))';
    }

    // editDie
    function editDie(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest('tr'));
        document.location.href = '@(Url.Action("Edit", "Dies"))' + '/' + dataItem.DieId.toString();
    }

    // deleteDie
    function deleteDie(e) {
        
    }
</script>
```

- Create.cshtml

```html
@model LabelArchive.Models.Die.DieModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Die";
}

<h2>Create Die</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DieModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
        <!--submit/create-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

- Edit.cshtml

```html
@model LabelArchive.Models.Die.DieModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Die";
}

<h2>Edit Die</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DieModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DieId)
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
        <!--submit/save-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

- _CreateOrEdit.cshtml (a partial view)

```html
@using LabelArchive.Models.DieShape
@model LabelArchive.Models.Die.DieModel
        <!--CompanyId-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @*<div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>*@
        </div>
         <!--DieShapeId-->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DieShapeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DieShapeId, new SelectList(Model.DieShapes, "DieShapeId", "Name"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DieShapeId, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
</div>
         <!--DieTypeId-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DieTypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DieTypeId, new SelectList(Model.DieTypes, "DieTypeId", "Name"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DieTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
         <!--Name-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
         <!--Width-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Width, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Width, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Width, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
         <!--Height-->
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Height, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Height, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Height, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My controller:**

- DiesController.cs

```js
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using LabelArchive.Logic.Die;
using LabelArchive.Logic.DieShape;
using LabelArchive.Logic.DieType;
using LabelArchive.Models.Die;


namespace LabelArchive.Controllers
{
    public class DiesController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Dies
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Die_Read
        public ActionResult Die_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var readRequest = Die.Get().ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(readRequest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        // GET: Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            DieModel model = new DieModel();
            model.DieShapes = DieShape.Get();
            model.DieTypes = DieType.Get();
            
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(DieModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Die.Create(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: Edit
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            DieModel model = Die.Get(id);
            return View(model);
        }

        // Post: Edit
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(DieModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Die.Update(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Die_Destroy
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Die_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, DieModel model)
        {
            if (model != null)
            {
                Die.Delete(model);
            }

            return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
    }
}
```

**My logic:**

- Dies.cs

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LabelArchive.Data;
using LabelArchive.Logic.AutomapperConfiguration;
using LabelArchive.Models.Die;

namespace LabelArchive.Logic.Die
{
    public class Die
    {
        // IsModelValid
        private static bool IsModelValid(DieModel model)
        {
            // If there is additional validation beyond data annotations, logic to process that additional validation goes here.
            return true;
        }

        // Get
        public static List<DieModel> Get(Expression<Func<Data.Die, bool>> predicate = null)
        {
            using (var db = new LabelArchiveEntities())
            {
                var mapper = DieMapper.Create();

                List<DieModel> dies;
                if (predicate == null)
                {

                    dies = mapper.Map<List<DieModel>>(db.Dies.ToList());
                }
                else
                {
                    dies = mapper.Map<List<DieModel>>(db.Dies.Where(predicate).ToList());
                }

                return dies;
            }
        }

        // Get
        public static DieModel Get(int id)
        {
            return Get(i => i.DieId == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        // Create
        public static DieModel Create(DieModel model)
        {
            if (!IsModelValid(model))
            {
                throw new Exception("This model is invalid.");
            }

            var mapper = DieMapper.Create();

            var die = mapper.Map<Data.Die>(model);


            using (var db = new LabelArchiveEntities())
            {
                db.Dies.Add(die);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            model.DieId = die.DieId;

            return model;
        }

        // Update
        public static DieModel Update(DieModel model)
        {
            if (!IsModelValid(model))
            {
                throw new Exception("This model is invalid.");
            }

            using (var db = new LabelArchiveEntities())
            {
                var mapper = DieMapper.Create();

                var die = db.Dies.Find(model.DieId);

                if (die != null)
                {
                    mapper.Map(model, die);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return model;
        }

        // Delete
        public static void Delete(DieModel model)
        {
            using (var db = new LabelArchiveEntities())
            {
                var die = db.Dies.Find(model.DieId);

                if (die != null)
                {
                    db.Dies.Remove(die);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My profile(mapping):**

- DieProfile.cs

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using LabelArchive.Models.Die;

namespace LabelArchive.Logic.AutomapperConfiguration
{
    public class DieProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            CreateMap<Data.Die, DieModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.DieShapeName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DieShape == null ? "" : s.DieShape.Name))
                .ForMember(d => d.DieTypeName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DieType == null ? "": s.DieType.Name));

            CreateMap<DieModel, Data.Die>();

        }
    }

    public static class DieMapper
    { 
        public static IMapper Create()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<DieProfile>();
             });

            return config.CreateMapper();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Model:**

- DieModel.cs

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LabelArchive.Models.DieShape;
using LabelArchive.Models.DieType;

namespace LabelArchive.Models.Die
{
    public class DieModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int DieId { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int DieShapeId { get; set; }
        public int DieTypeId { get; set; }
        public string DieShapeName { get; set; }
        public string DieTypeName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Width { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DieShapeModel> DieShapes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DieTypeModel> DieTypes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have posted too much code. Please only post the code that's relevant to your question (the grid).

Comment: Also, if you want edit and create to redirect to a different page, why are you using an Ajax grid and not a server one?

Comment: Also `.net fullstack(MVC, EF, Kendo, etc...)` Kendo is NOT part of the .net stack.